# Save all modification operations for custom list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have custom list in SharePoint 2013, there are many edit operation on each item for the list , I want to save all the operation’s, then I can extract to Excel file ( like report for these operations ).

My question is:

Can I do it with No-Code solution ? if yes , how?

If I need to do it with Code, what’s an appropriate solution to do it , using ( client-side object model (CSOM) , build an application by .Net ,etc.) ?

Comment: You mean you need some sort of auditing?

Comment: You can consider it as you say

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SharePoint [audit logging functionality](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/pages/how-to-enable-audit-functionality-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that.

1. use the inbuilt audit log functionality
2. Create an event reciver in the code which will make an entry in the log file as per your requiremnet
3. Create a workflow for the Item Added and Updated events and generate a log file for the same.

Comment: For creating  workflow option, can I do it with SharePoint designer?

Comment: I think yes, you can make a log entry in the Workflow Hostory list. But I am not sure about how will you get the data about which entry has changed or created .. Sorry. But if you want to create custom WF then create custom activity using that you can log entry in your custom list too